# Get same time interval from date range in moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Suppose,
I have date range:

```
var start = moment('2017-08-21').startOf('isoweek').startOf('day');
var end = moment('2017-08-21').startOf('isoweek').add('days', 4).endOf('day');
```

And I have another array:

```
var array = [
   {x:Mon Aug 21 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   {x:Mon Aug 21 2017 08:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:6},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 07:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:4},
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 08:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 15:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:9},
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 22:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:1},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 23 2017 06:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:5},
   {x:Mon Aug 23 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   {x:Mon Aug 23 2017 23:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 07:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:4},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 12:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 15:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:8},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 19:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:7},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 23:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 27 2017 06:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:5},
   {x:Mon Aug 27 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   {x:Mon Aug 27 2017 23:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   ...
];
```

What I need here to do is change value of y = 0 if time is not in range between:

'08:05:00' to 22:05:00

Means my output must look like this:

```
var array = [
   {x:Mon Aug 21 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   {x:Mon Aug 21 2017 08:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:6},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 07:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 08:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 15:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:9},
   {x:Mon Aug 22 2017 22:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:1},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 23 2017 06:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   {x:Mon Aug 23 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   {x:Mon Aug 23 2017 23:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 07:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 12:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:3},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 15:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:8},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 19:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:7},
   {x:Mon Aug 25 2017 23:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   ...
   {x:Mon Aug 27 2017 06:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   {x:Mon Aug 27 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   {x:Mon Aug 27 2017 23:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),y:0},
   ...
];
```

What I have tried till now

```
$.each(arr, function (key, value) {
      var date = moment(value.x);
      //if (date < start || date > end])) {
      //@TODO where i need to check time interval also
        filterArray.push({
          x: date,
          y: 0
        })
      } else {
        filterArray.push({
          x: date,
          y: value.y
        })
      }
    });
```

I try to see for time interval with date range but no luck. Can anyone provide me suggestion or help?

Comment: you said `between: '08:05:00' to 10:05:00` but your example seems to imply `between: '08:05:00' to 22:05:00`

Comment: @phuzi yap you are right, I apologize

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `x` property is a JavaScript Date object and with `var date = moment(value.x);` you are calling [`moment(Date);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/).

You can use [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) that:

> Check if a moment is between two other moments, optionally looking at unit scale (minutes, hours, days, etc). The match is exclusive.

In your case, you can pass `'[]'` as forth parameter to make [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) inclusive.

You can simply use `date.isBetween(start, end, null, '[]')` to check if an element is in the range between `start` and `end`.

Then you can use `isBetween` to check if your element time is between `08:05:00` and `22:05:00` building 3 moment object for the same day (today in my example, since *Omitted units default to 0 or the current date, month, and year.* as stated in the docs of [`moment({unit: value, ...});`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/)). So you will have:

- `today805` that represent the current day at `08:05:00`
- `today2205` that represent the current day at `22:05:00`
- `time` that is a moment object for the current day with the time of the `x` property (of the current element of the `$.each` loop)

So you can use `time.isBetween(today805, today2205, null, '[]')` to check if the element's time is between `08:05:00` and `22:05:00`. This will compare *"only"* time because the three moments represents the same day *by construction*.

You can get hours and minutes of the `x` properties of the `array` elements using both moment's getters ([`hours()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/) and [`minutes()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/)) and native Date getters ([`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) and [`getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes))

Here a working sample:

```js
var start = moment('2017-08-21').startOf('isoweek').startOf('day');
var end = moment('2017-08-21').startOf('isoweek').add(4, 'days').endOf('day');

var array = [
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 21, 8, 0), y:3},
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 21, 8, 5), y:6},
   //...
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 22, 7, 5), y:4},
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 22, 8, 5), y:3},
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 22, 15, 5),y:9},
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 22, 22, 5),y:1},
   //...
   //...
   //...
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 27, 6, 5), y:5},
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 27, 8, 0), y:3},
   {x: new Date(2017, 7, 27, 23, 5),y:3},
   //...
];

var filterArray = [];
// Today at 08:05:00
var today805  = moment({h: 8, m: 5});
// Today at 22:05:00
var today2205 = moment({h: 22, m: 5});

$.each(array, function (key, value) {
  var date = moment(value.x);
  // Create a moment object for the current day with hours and minutes of value.x
  var time = moment({h: date.hours(), m: date.minutes()});
  var yVal;
  if( date.isBetween(start, end, null, '[]') && 
      time.isBetween(today805, today2205, null, '[]') ) {
    yVal = 0;
  } else {
    yVal = value.y;
  }
  filterArray.push({
    x: date.format(),
    y: yVal
  });
});

console.log(filterArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```